# Need help fixing this jump buffer (Problem: Player occasionally double jumps)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rigid-bodies

I tried to make a simple Jump buffer and Coyote timer.
As you can see, sometimes the player does a double jump, but only if the jump button is clicked very fast.

As you can see <[here](https://youtu.be/cgbIiT6LtWM)>, it only happens a few times.

```
[Header("Player Accesiblility")]
 public float hangTime = 1.5f;
 [SerializeField]
 private float hangCounter;
 [SerializeField]
 private float jumpTimer;
 public float jumpDelay = 0.25f;

private void FixedUpdate()
 {
     if (jumpTimer > Time.time && coll.onGround)
     {
         Jump(Vector2.up, false);
     }
 }
Void update(){

 if (coll.onGround) //Coyote Time for Jump
     {
         hangCounter = hangTime;
     }

     if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump")) //Jump Function
      {
         anim.SetTrigger("jump");

         jumpTimer = Time.time + jumpDelay;
         if (!coll.onGround && hangCounter > 0)
         {
             Jump(Vector2.up, false);
             hangCounter = 0;
         }


         if (coll.onWall && !coll.onGround)
          {

             WallJump();
          }
      }
}
 private void Jump(Vector2 dir, bool wall)
  {
     rb.velocity = new Vector2(rb.velocity.x, 0);
      rb.velocity += dir * jumpForce;
     jumpTimer = 0f;
     hangCounter = 0;
  }
```

Any help will be much appreciated, and thank you for your time.

Comment: It's mostly likely because you're doing physics in `Update` and not in `FixedUpdate`. Read [this to know more](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.FixedUpdate.html)

Comment: @Mateusz Thank you
I will give it try

Comment: We know questions have been dealt with successfully when you accept an answer. Nothing stops that from being your own answer, if necessary (or you could encourage Mateusz to expand on their comment). We don't edit titles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got an answer from @Mateusz that helped me.
His comment:
It's mostly likely because you're doing physics in Update and not in FixedUpdate. Read this to know more (https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.FixedUpdate.html)